# Getting HTML/XML Elements And Values In Java

Tags: java, html

Can somebody help me get the elements from a HTML page? I don't want to use a library, I just want a pointer or two on how the use the correct regexes and such. I'm kind of stuck on this, all help is appreciated.

Comment: Because he mentioned regex, and somebody was going to do it anyway. OP, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to decide first whether you're talking about HTML or XML.

If your text is a valid XML document, then you can use JAXP to parse the document and access elements/attributes programatically (no need in regular expressions).

If your text is not a valid XML document, then no set regular expressions is ever going to work for you in 100% of the cases; the best you can do is use the JDK's built-in HTML parser, provided as part of the Swing framework.

Answer (score 0):

The JDK includes a rudimentary [HTML parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/package-summary.html). It isn't very robust, but you did specify that you "don't want to use a library". So... knock yourself out, I suppose?